# Strapi Bundle/Group Collection-Types

Tags: strapi

Is it possible to bundle up collection-types in Strapi?

What I mean by this:
For example, our website has a Media&Downloads page. This page consists of several categories (Logos, Poster, Press-Releases etc.)
All of these categories are reflected as own collection-type inside Strapi.
Now one request of the editors' is, that they want all these collection-types regarding certain pages bundled up. Inside Strapi, you would then on the collection-type navigation(left side) only have the "Press & Media" type, and when you click on it, it acts like an accordion and all the real collection-types are being displayed.

Comment: hello, i want to implement the same functionally, did you find any solution?

Comment: Perhaps a solution has never been found?